# Ford Figo doesn't start after recharging the battery

Tags: engine, ford

I have a Ford Figo. I had the battery recharged. Now the car won't start. There is a symbol which has pic of a car and a lock on it and that keeps blinking whenever I try to start and engine doesn't start. please help

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that's the security check light. Not sure what caused your issues to start with (other than a dead battery), but sounds like the car has lost track of the key(s) and now is in 'secure' mode. You'll probably have to have a Ford tech look at it with a scanner to figure out what the problem is and how to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not cranking even? If not, then I strongly suggest a hard reset of ECU and Engine Immobiliser.